# PySpark: how to get min/max across group until a condition is met, where the condition depends on the min/max?

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, aggregation

I want to find the minimum of column A and maximum of column B in a PySpark DataFrame across a certain window (in an expanding window style). If the maximum of column A is larger than the minimum of column B, then I want to set the minimum of column B to None and re-start the window. I want to do the same if the minimum of column B is smaller than the maximum of column A.

For the following table:

```
+--------+----+-----+
|     row|   A|    B|
+--------+----+-----+
|       1|null|   15|
|       2|  10|   14|
|       3|  11| null|
|       4|null|   17|
|       5|  12| null|
|       6|null|   10|
|       7|   7|   10|
|       8|  11|   10|
|       9|  12|   14|
+--------+----+-----+
```

I would expect a result of:

```
+--------+----+-----+
|     row|minA| minB|
+--------+----+-----+
|       1|null|   15|
|       2|  10|   14|
|       3|  11|   14|
|       4|  11|   14|
|       5|  12|   14|
|       6|null|   10|
|       7|   7|   10|
|       8|  11| null|
|       9|  12|   14|
+--------+----+-----+
```

I feel like I should be able to do this with some smart window partitioning, but I can't figure out how to dynamically access the running maximum/minimum.

Comment: Write a custom scala aggregation function and register it as UDF in pyspark and use it in your Window function